# Multi divs into container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fill Container with 40 or more DIVs.
.cxori height and width must change automatically if i chang TOTAL number

This is my code URL: http://jsfiddle.net/kakha13/Lsfkukm0/1/

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

jquery

```
var total  = 40;

for(i=0;i<total;i++){
$("<div class='cxori'></div>").appendTo($(".container"));
}

var cxori = ($('.container').height() +  $('.container').width()) / total;
$(".cxori").css("height",cxori+'px');
$(".cxori").css("width",cxori+'px');
```

css

```
.container {
    padding:0;margin:0;
    margin:3px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:grey; 
    border:1px solid black;
}

.cxori {
    z-index:11111;
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: use percentage for width , not fixed pixels

Comment: What is the question? `.cxori` height and width must change to what ?

Comment: I think you need to use `Math.sqrt`. Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/LmktgLey/ ? Do you want to calculate the width and height so that the divs fill the container?

Comment: @KhanhTO it's working . thanks :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n6b8czfg/1/ ?

Comment: I posted as an answer. You could mark as accepted if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [Math.sqrt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt). Try:

```
var total = 100;

for(i=0;i<total;i++){
$("<div class='cxori'></div>").appendTo($(".container"));
}

var totalPerDimension = Math.sqrt(total);

var width = $('.container').width() / totalPerDimension;
var height =  $('.container').height() / totalPerDimension;
$(".cxori").css("height",width+'px');
$(".cxori").css("width",height+'px');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmktgLey/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be something like:

```
var total = 42;

for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    $("<div class='cxori'></div>").appendTo($(".container"));
}

//asuming equal
var cntX = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(total));
var cntY = Math.ceil(total / cntX);

var cxori = $('.container').width() / cntX;
var cyori = $('.container').height() / cntY;

$(".cxori").css("height", cxori + 'px');
$(".cxori").css("width", cyori + 'px');
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsfkukm0/3/)

It still has some rounding error. This needs to be handled additionaly.
Had no spontaneous idea how to solve this...