# How to make nested divs resize based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing a project from [The Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.com/web-development-101/javascript-and-jquery). Basically [this](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/pauldd91/theodinproject/master/sketch_pad/index.html).

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/sketch.css">
    <script src="js/sketch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="grid_controls">
    <button class="clear">Clear</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/*=================
General
=================*/

body {
    background: aqua;
}

/*=================
Sketchpad Holder
=================*/
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}

.box {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    left: 0.5%;
    right: auto;
    position: relative;
}


.clear {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
var default_grid_num = 435;
var div_limit = prompt("How large would you like your grid to be?");
var button_prompt = "Would you like to redraw the grids?";
/*var div_limit = prompt("number")*/
$(document).ready(function() {

for(var i = 1; i <= div_limit; i++)
    $(".container").append("<div class='box'></div>");

$(".container > div").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});

$("button").click(function() {
    $(".box").fadeOut();
    if(confirm("Would you like to redraw the grid?")); 
    {
        boxes_per_row = prompt("Define width of grid.");
    }
});


});
```

What I want to do is get user input(`.div_limit`) and resize the divs(`.box`) based on the users input(`.div_limit`) So if the user only typed in the number one, the one div would take up the whole container box.

Here is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/zappdapper/full/epdPKb/

I know I can do this, but how?

Comment: Something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717869/multi-divs-into-container

Comment: By the looks of it, you want to translate a number to a percentage so that each box takes up a certain amount of the container's space, correct?

Comment: @VincentWilkie that is exactly what I want. Couldn't have said it better.

Comment: @zappdapper - I've updated my answer based on your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p63t3beL/4/) that uses the mod operator `%` and some math to determine a percentage for the boxes.

I've included `max_per_row` as well to determine how many should show in a row.

Comment: This might work, but how would I integrate it into my current code?

Comment: I'd say just try some things out. Based on the code in your question; the for loop in the jsfiddle would be where your for loop is and `var limit` from the jsfiddle would be your `div_limit`. Also, `max_per_row` is your `boxes_per_row`

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I've taken another look at your example and your comment and come up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xw4cbo5n/

I edited the example slightly so that instead of asking two questions, only one is asked: "How many boxes per row of grid" (this is similar to your example).

It then goes on to draw out a grid where each row contains that number and sets each bow width and height accordingly. I also edited your CSS styles slightly.

Is that closer to what you're looking for?

---

I've created a JSFiddle which displays two prompts when run:

1) How many boxes would you like?

2) How many boxes should take up one row?

http://jsfiddle.net/5vg6n232/

After the responses are given, the grid is drawn.

I've edited your CSS slightly but the main functionality is driven by a couple of functions:

`function drawBoxes(){`

takes care of adding the correct number on divs to the page. After this is done it calls:

`function restyle(numberofBoxesPerRow){`

which simply reset's the CSS width of each box based on how may boxes per row the user specified.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This is useful, but not quite what I am looking for. I would prefer that the nested divs take up the whole area of the container. For instance, if the user only wanted one div, that one div would fill 100% of the container. Any way I could do that?